# Unknown Sql Exception (Number = 102, Message=Incorrect syntax near ','.)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, syntax, syntax-error

I got this syntax error near ','

I already tried some solutions as this question is already asked in this forum before, but to no avail.

```
string sqlSelect = "SELECT"
+ " 'RI' AS DocType, DebtorCode, DocNo, DocDate, [Description]"
+ ",SalesAgent, LocalNetTotal AS LocalAmount,"
+ "(Outstanding * CurrencyRate) AS LocalBalance"
+ " FROM ARINVOICE"
+ " WHERE Cancelled = 'F'"
+ " UNION"
+ " SELECT 'RD' AS DocType, DebtorCode, DocNo, DocDate, [Description]"
+ ",SalesAgent, LocalNetTotal AS LocalAmount"
+ ",Outstanding AS LocalBalance"
+ " FROM ARDN"
+ " WHERE Cancelled = 'F'"
+ " UNION"
+ " SELECT 'RC' AS DocType, DebtorCode, DocNo, DocDate, [Description]"
+ ",'' AS SalesAgent, LocalNetTotal AS LocalAmount"
+ ",(NetTotal - KnockOffAmt + RefundAmt) * CurrencyRate AS LocalBalance"
+ " FROM ARCN"
+ " WHERE Cancelled = 'F'"
+ " UNION"
+ " SELECT 'RP' AS 'DocType', 'DebtorCode', 'DocNo', 'DocDate', 
[Description]"
+ ",'' AS SalesAgent, LocalPaymentAmt AS LocalAmount"
+ ",LocalUnappliedAmount AS LocalBalance"
+ " FROM ARPAYMENT"
+ " WHERE Cancelled = 'F'";
```

Is their anything wrong with my query? Because i already check it for 2 days and could not find any mistakes, not that i known.
Hope anyone could help.

Comment: what is the error message ?  Can you show the complete query ? You seems to miss the `@` at declare `@sqlSelect`. And why double quote instead of single quote ?

Comment: I was also going to ask why double quotes and not single..

Answer (score 1):

have u tried to unquote the DocType ?

```
string sqlSelect = "SELECT"
+ " 'RI' AS DocType, DebtorCode, DocNo, DocDate, [Description]"
+ ",SalesAgent, LocalNetTotal AS LocalAmount,"
+ "(Outstanding * CurrencyRate) AS LocalBalance"
+ " FROM ARINVOICE"
+ " WHERE Cancelled = 'F'"
+ " UNION"
+ " SELECT 'RD' AS DocType, DebtorCode, DocNo, DocDate, [Description]"
+ ",SalesAgent, LocalNetTotal AS LocalAmount"
+ ",Outstanding AS LocalBalance"
+ " FROM ARDN"
+ " WHERE Cancelled = 'F'"
+ " UNION"
+ " SELECT 'RC' AS DocType, DebtorCode, DocNo, DocDate, [Description]"
+ ",'' AS SalesAgent, LocalNetTotal AS LocalAmount"
+ ",(NetTotal - KnockOffAmt + RefundAmt) * CurrencyRate AS LocalBalance"
+ " FROM ARCN"
+ " WHERE Cancelled = 'F'"
+ " UNION"
+ " SELECT 'RP' AS DocType, DebtorCode, DocNo, DocDate, 
[Description]"
+ ",'' AS SalesAgent, LocalPaymentAmt AS LocalAmount"
+ ",LocalUnappliedAmount AS LocalBalance"
+ " FROM ARPAYMENT"
+ " WHERE Cancelled = 'F'";
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL SERVER, check below script-

```
declare @sqlSelect nvarchar(max)
select @sqlSelect = N' 
SELECT ''RI'' AS DocType,DebtorCode,DocNo,DocDate,[Description],SalesAgent,LocalNetTotal AS LocalAmount,
(Outstanding * CurrencyRate) AS LocalBalance 
FROM ARINVOICE WHERE Cancelled = ''F''
UNION
SELECT ''RD'' AS DocType,DebtorCode,DocNo,DocDate,[Description],SalesAgent,LocalNetTotal AS LocalAmount,Outstanding AS LocalBalance
FROM ARDN WHERE Cancelled = ''F''
UNION
SELECT ''RC'' AS DocType,DebtorCode,DocNo,DocDate,[Description],'''' AS SalesAgent,LocalNetTotal AS LocalAmount,
((NetTotal - KnockOffAmt + RefundAmt) * CurrencyRate) AS LocalBalance
FROM ARCN WHERE Cancelled = ''F''
UNION
SELECT ''RP'' AS DocType,DebtorCode,DocNo,DocDate,[Description],'''' AS SalesAgent,LocalPaymentAmt AS LocalAmount,
LocalUnappliedAmount AS LocalBalance
FROM ARPAYMENT WHERE Cancelled = ''F'' '

print (@sqlSelect)

--exec (@sqlSelect)
```